# How to convert this days of week to bitmask?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I have a method that converts a bitmask to a list of days using an Enum. I am trying to do the reverse, but am having trouble. I have `DaysOfWeekToEnum` working, but not `DaysOfWeekFromEnum`. Below is what I am trying to do. Can anyone help?

```
public static short DaysOfWeekFromEnum(IEnumerable<DaysInWeekIds> daysOfWeek)
{
    short mask;

    foreach (var item in daysOfWeek)
    {
        mask &= item; // ????
    }

    return mask
}

public static IEnumerable<DaysInWeekIds> DaysOfWeekToEnum(short mask)
{
    var values = new List<DaysInWeekIds>();

    foreach (short enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DaysInWeekIds)))
    {
        if (mask & enumValue == enumValue)
        {
            values.Add((DaysInWeekIds) Enum.ToObject(typeof(DaysInWeekIds),
                enumValue));
        }
    }

    return values;
}

/// <summary> The days in week ids. </summary>
public enum DaysInWeekIds : short
{
    M = 1,
    Tu = 2,
    W = 4,
    Th = 8,
    F = 16,
    Sa = 32,
    Su = 64
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `|=`, not `&=`, to set the additional bits.

You could also join string representations together, and pass the result to `Enum.Parse` method. This is not as efficient, but the code will look shorter.

```
var res = (DaysInWeekIds)Enum.Parse(
    typeof(DaysInWeekIds)
,   string.Join(",", daysOfWeek.Select(d => d.ToString()).ToArray())
);
```

This returns `25` for `{M, Th, F}` ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/SCBSW)).

Comment: Depending on your version of .NET, the `.ToArray()` might be unnecessary.

Comment: @TimS. That is true -- I added `ToArray()` to make it compile on ideone, which runs mono.